# Add new line after list character or binary - Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a list like this:

> List =   [<<"Lucky Labon: Hey">>,<<"Lucky Labon: Keep?">>,
>                        <<"Lucky Labon: Alpine is...">>]

I am trying to join all the items in one but with a new line.

My attempt is like this:

```
lists:foldl(fun(X,A2) -> lists:append(A2, binary_to_list(X)) end, [], List).
```

The result is :

```
"Lucky Labon: HeyLucky Labon: Keep?Lucky Labon: Alpine is..."
```

Almost what I want, I need a new line after each string something like

```
"Lucky Labon: Hey
 Lucky Labon: Keep?
 Lucky Labon: Alpine is..."
```

Comment: http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/list-join-for-erlang-td2098783.html

Answer (score 5):

If you just need to print the result, use the concept of iolist:

> iolist() = maybe_improper_list(byte() | binary() | iolist(), binary()
>   | [])

you can then easily transform your list like this:

```
1> ListOfSentences  = [<<"Lucky Labon: Hey">>,<<"Lucky Labon: Keep?">>, <<"Lucky Labon: Alpine is...">>],
1> PrintableList = [[X,"\n"] || X <- ListOfSentences],
1> io:format("~s",[PrintableList]).
Lucky Labon: Hey         
Lucky Labon: Keep?
Lucky Labon: Alpine is...
ok
2>
```

Doing this you avoid useless copies of the intermediate lists.

Comment: I don't need to print it. I need to pass this value to a HTML text so that it displays with the correct spacing, would `"Lucky Labon: Hey\nLucky Labon: Keep?\nLucky Labon: Alpine is...\n"`  be understood by the html?

Comment: No, as far as I know you need to insert line break line (<br>) or paragraphs (<p> .... </p>) if you want that the browser to print a line break.

Comment: which web server do you use? Generally the erlang implementation understand the erlang terms.

Answer (score 3):

There is this thing in Erlang called `iolist`. It's is one of the greatest thing invented after sliced bread. (I personally thing sliced bread is not great at all but it is the phrase commonly used so I will keep it.) It is a format which allows you to perform a lot of operations very efficient. For example, if you would like just append a newline after each binary in your `List`.

```
> List = [<<"Lucky Labon: Hey">>,<<"Lucky Labon: Keep?">>, <<"Lucky Labon: Alpine is...">>].
[<<"Lucky Labon: Hey">>,<<"Lucky Labon: Keep?">>,
 <<"Lucky Labon: Alpine is...">>]
> S = [[X,$\n] || X <- List].
[[<<"Lucky Labon: Hey">>,10],
 [<<"Lucky Labon: Keep?">>,10],
 [<<"Lucky Labon: Alpine is...">>,10]]
```

It is basically O(N) operation where N is a number of binaries in your list. It can't be more efficient than that. There is not involved any data copying of original binaries. There is very minimal overhead and all of the standard library working with IO operations supports handling of iolists. You always could change iolist into binary or perform IO operation with it.

```
> iolist_to_binary(S).    
<<"Lucky Labon: Hey\nLucky Labon: Keep?\nLucky Labon: Alpine is...\n">>
> io:put_chars(S).
Lucky Labon: Hey
Lucky Labon: Keep?
Lucky Labon: Alpine is...
ok
```

IO operation or turning into binary of iolist is O(N) operation where N is the size of the output. It can't be more efficient than that. (The IO subsystem can even use writev() system call which avoids any userspace buffer copying at all and makes IO even more efficient.) The simple rule of thumb is to use iolist whenever you don't have a very good reason not to.

Comment: yes, using `$\n` instead of `"\n"` is a even more optimized :o) , I thought about it to late, when I re-read the iolist definition.

Answer (score -3):

```
1> io:format("~s", [lists:foldl(fun(X,A2) -> lists:append(A2, 
binary_to_list(X) ++ "\n") end, [], List)]).
Lucky Labon: Hey
Lucky Labon: Keep?
Lucky Labon: Alpine is...
ok
2>
```

Comment: It's hard to think about the more inefficient way how to do it.

Comment: Well, the OP provided a tiny data set and didn’t ask for a solution for a high volume production system with huge data... ;)

Comment: There is not any point to learn bad habits and wrong ideas when you can do it right from start and solution is even simpler that the wrong one.

Comment: Indeed, no doubt.